# Quiet Sound on 12.10, ThinkPad T530

Tags: sound, 12.10, volume-control

Everything in alsamixer is maxed. What other things can I try?

My audio device is:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a BIOS update available for similar laptop models that include, you can check their website to get it:
Fixed an issue where no sound was heard from the ThinkPad internal
        speakers while the computer was locked when SmartAudio was set to
        Multi-stream mode and headphones or external speakers were attached to
        the computer. This fix is to follow Windows' behavior.
        (Hint)
        To disable sound from the internal speakers in lock state, press the
        mute button on the keyboard.

Changelog: http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/g4uj14uc.txt